# Finding the point of intersection of 3 Numpy Arrays Python

Tags: python, list, function, numpy, intersection

I am trying to code a function where it gives me the indexes of where either `list_2` or `list_3`crosses `list_`. So it would give me the points of intersection if there are any in numpy code. I want to get the crosses in order, so the list of indexes have to be formatted so that it would give me a cross in order of `list_2 cross, list_3 cross , list_2 cross` or `list_3 cross, list_2 cross , list_3 cross` etc. So if a cross has happened it has to wait for the other array values to cross the `list` before it can go through. I do not know how I can go through with this though I have tried using a `numpy.where()`function and such, I am also using the pandas module so if it has a valid function for this I could use that too.

variables:

```
list_ = np.array([9887.89 9902.99 9902.99 9910.23 9920.79 9911.34 9920.01 9927.51 9932.3
 9932.33 9928.87 9929.22 9929.22 9935.24 9935.24 9935.26 9935.26 9935.68
 9935.68 9940.5 ])
list_2 = np.array([9935.26 9935.26 9935.68 9935.68 9940.5  9925.19 9925.19 9929.62 9929.65
 9929.93 9932.55 9936.81 9936.84 9937.26 9932.55 9932.55 9932.55 9932.6
 9932.6  9932.6])
list_3_ = np.array([9928.87 9929.22 9929.22 9935.24 9935.24 9935.26 9935.26 9935.68 9935.68
 9940.5  9925.19 9925.19 9929.62 9929.65 9929.93 9932.55 9936.81 9936.84
 9937.26 9932.55])
```

plot:

[image]

Expected Output:

```
List_2 cross at 5, List_3 cross at 10, List_2 cross at 14, List_3 cross at 15, List_2 cross at 18, List_3 cross at 19
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for (with `return_indices=True`)? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html

Comment: Are the lists the same length?

Comment: Can you illustrate what you mean by showing what the return value would be for your example data

Comment: yes they are the same size, I will update it by giving a graphical values

Comment: @Stuart hopefully the explanation is better now I have updated it. I could use the `intersect1d()` function I think but I dont really know how to format it.

Comment: `intersect1d` does something different from what you seem to be looking for (like set intersection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crossing points or intersection indices between two series `a` and `b` are the indices `i` where:

- either (a<sub>i</sub> < b<sub>i</sub> and a<sub>i+1</sub> > b<sub>i+1</sub>) (`b` crosses `a` from above)
- or (a<sub>i</sub> > b<sub>i</sub> and a<sub>i+1</sub> < b<sub>i+1</sub>) (`b` crosses `a` from below)
- or a<sub>i</sub> = b<sub>i</sub> (`a` and `b` touch)

So we can get the indices by comparing the 'current' (*i*-th) and 'next' (*i+1*-th) values of each array.

```
def intersection_points(a, *others):
    if a.ndim != 1 or any(other.shape != a.shape for other in others):
        raise ValueError('The arrays must be single dimensional and the same length')
    others = np.array(others)
    indices = np.argwhere(
            ((a[:-1] < others[..., :-1]) & (a[1:] > others[..., 1:])) |  
            ((a[:-1] > others[..., :-1]) & (a[1:] < others[..., 1:])) | 
            (a[:-1] == others[..., :-1]))
    return indices[indices[:, 1].argsort()]   # sort by i

a = np.array([9887.89, 9902.99, 9902.99, 9910.23, 9920.79, 9911.34, 9920.01, 9927.51, 9932.3, 9932.33, 9928.87, 9929.22, 9929.22, 9935.24, 9935.24, 9935.26, 9935.26, 9935.68, 9935.68, 9940.5])
b = np.array([9935.26, 9935.26, 9935.68, 9935.68, 9940.5, 9925.19, 9925.19, 9929.62, 9929.65, 9929.93, 9932.55, 9936.81, 9936.84, 9937.26, 9932.55, 9932.55, 9932.55, 9932.6, 9932.6, 9932.6])
c = np.array([9928.87, 9929.22, 9929.22, 9935.24, 9935.24, 9935.26, 9935.26, 9935.68, 9935.68, 9940.5, 9925.19, 9925.19, 9929.62, 9929.65, 9929.93, 9932.55, 9936.81, 9936.84, 9937.26, 9932.55])
print(intersection_points(a, b, c))
```

This returns an array of intersection points in this format:

```
[[ 0  7]
 [ 0  9]
 [ 1  9]
 [ 1 11]
 [ 1 12]
 [ 0 13]
 [ 1 15]
 [ 1 18]]
```

meaning that `b` (your `list_2`) intersects with `a` at indices 7, 9, 13, and `c` (your `list_3`) intersects with `a` at indices 9, 11, 12, 15 and 18.

You seem to want the returned value to somehow alternate between intersections of the different lines and 'wait for the other array values to cross the list before it can go through'. It's not entirely clear what this would mean in every case but you can possibly do this by manipulating the result like this:

```
ip = intersection_points(a, b, c)
print(np.concatenate(([ip[0]], ip[1:][ip[:-1, 0] != ip[1:, 0]])))
```

returning

```
[[ 0,  7],
 [ 1,  9],
 [ 0, 13],
 [ 1, 15]]
```

i.e. the first crossing is of `b` at index 7, then `c` at 9, then `b` at 13, and finally `c` at 15.

Comment: I tried to implement this to a large dataset with the length of 2.7 million arrays. It gave me a value error. `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: One more question what does `*others` do in the program does it take in the extra `lists` other than the main list?

Comment: What shape are your arrays? If they are 1 dimensional like a, b and c in the example then it shouldn't matter how long they are.

Comment: Yes `*others` allows you to specify as many extra arrays as you want as arguments in the function

Comment: Yes they are all 1 dimensional with a b and c having a length of  2666447 each the error message is `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2669446,) (2,2666446) ` I am going to make a new issue about it. 
`

Comment: Here is the link to the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65944276/getting-the-points-of-intersection-of-a-large-numpy-array-python

Comment: See my edit to the function which adds a check that the arrays are all one-dimensional and the same length - do you still get the same error?

Comment: the a array length was larger then b and c it was a foolish mistake I did. I fixed it, thanks for the code.

Comment: Hey sorry for bothering too much I tried to add a bit where it labels the order of the crossings for the code but I wasn't very successfull. If you could take a look at this issue I would appreciate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949418/adding-labels-to-line-crossings-in-numpy-python

Comment: You can convert the 0s and 1s into labels using something like `np.array(['b', 'c'])[ip[:, 0]]`

Comment: I am trying to implement the last index of of the `a` as a part of the indexes, i have made a issue about it if you could take a look at it I would appreciate it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124955/modifying-a-points-of-intersection-function-with-numpy-python

Comment: Hello there it has been a while, I am trying to write a code similar to the answer to this question. I would really appreciate it if you would take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782285/numpy-array-crossing-2-values-and-gets-the-index

Answer (score 0):

This function converts arrays to lists and returns a list of tuples:

```
def find_cross(list_, list_2, list_3):
    
    list_ = list_.tolist()
    list_2 = list_2.tolist()
    list_3 = list_3.tolist()
    
    cross = []
    i=0
    for x,y in zip(list_2, list_3):
        if x in list_:
            cross.append((i, list_.index(x)))
        if y in list_:
            cross.append((i, list_.index(y)))
        i+=1
    return cross
```