# Numpy array crossing 2 values and gets the index

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, indexing

I am trying to code a function where it gives me the indexes of where the values of `lower` or `upper` either gets crossed or touched by `a`.  I want to get the crosses in order, so the list of indexes have to be formatted so that it would give me a cross in order of upper cross signified by 1 and lower cross signified by 0, as can be seen in the expected output. So it will go like `upper,lower,upper,lower...` number form: `1,0,1,0...`. How would I be able to get the expected output for the code below since it is not working?

There is a cross when:

```
ai = index of the a array
bi = index of either upper or lower values (9930,9000)

either (ai < bi and ai+1 > bi+1) (b crosses a from above)
or (ai > bi and ai+1 < bi+1) (b crosses a from below)
or ai = bi (a and b touch)
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def intersection_points(a, *others):
    others = np.array(others)
    indices = np.argwhere(
            ((a[:-1] < others[-1]) & (a[1:] > others[-1])) |  
            ((a[:-1] > others[-1]) & (a[1:] < others[-1])) | 
            (a[:-1] == others[-1]))
    return indices[indices[:, 1].argsort()]   # sort by i

a = np.array([9887.89, 9902.99, 9902.99, 9910.23, 9920.79, 9911.34, 9920.01, 9927.51, 9932.3, 9932.33, 9928.87, 9929.22, 9929.22, 9935.24, 9830, 9735.26, 9835.26, 9835.68, 9935.68, 9840.5])
lower = np.array([9900])
upper = np.array([9930])

ip = intersection_points(a, lower, upper)
```

Expected output

```
lower cross specified by 0
upper cross specified by 1
[[ 0  1]
 [ 1  7]
 [ 0  13]
 [ 1  17]
 [ 0  18]
 [ 1  19]]
```

Comment: What are `b` and `c`?

Comment: Are you sure your desired output is correct? [Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT9rI.png).

Comment: You are right I changed the expected output my bad @Ivan. Also `b` and 'c' were supposed to be `upper` and `lower` so also fixed that thanks for letting me know

Comment: What I don't quite get is that the first two crosses are *lower crosses*: one on the lower bound, and the second on the upper bound. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I don't quite get is that the first two crossings are *lower* crossings: one on the *lower* bound, and another on the *upper* bound.

Anyhow, we can work on the two bounds separately regardless. This method uses a combination of [`np.logical_or`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) and [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html), as well as [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to retrieve the indices.

The array mask is given by:

```
>>> mask_b = np.logical_or(
      np.logical_or((a < b)*(np.roll(a, -1) > b), 
                    (a > b)*(np.roll(a, -1) < b)),
      a == b)

>>> mask_b.nonzero()[0]
array([ 7,  9, 12, 13, 17, 18])
```

Looking at a single bound, here the *upper* bound we have the data crossing it as `0`, `1`, `0`, `1`, `0`, and `1`.

Similarly for the *lower* bound `c`:

```
>>> mask_c = np.logical_or(
      np.logical_or((a < c)*(np.roll(a, -1) > c), 
                    (a > c)*(np.roll(a, -1) < c)),
      a == c)

>>> mask_c.nonzero()[0]
array([ 0, 13, 17, 18])
```

Here again, we have `0`, `1`, `0`, and `1` crossings.

You can check this matches well with the following plot I sent:

[image]

Comment: How could I combine the two of them to get the Expected Output

Comment: Your desired output seems wrong, you have a  total of 10 crossings (you can count on the plot), yet you only observed 6 in your output array.

Comment: Yea I see that you are right. I am just curious as to how you got the plots for the crosses because the masks shows different values

Comment: I plotted `a` then added the horizontal lines at *9900* and *9930*. You can compare the blue/red crossings with the indices given by the two masks: `array([ 7,  9, 12, 13, 17, 18])` and `array([ 0, 13, 17, 18])`.